# Pagination displaying full list on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination

I have taken my project and have a sample of it on codepen.
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RrzjGK

(Don't worry about the API key, I'll reset that later)

I have a data set that I am pulling from an external source and am using jquery to pull JSON and display the results on a page.

I am trying to use pagination to display more results than the page would normally allow. But the problem I am encountering is that on the initial page load, pagination is not functioning correctly and is displaying the full data set. Once you start using the buttons to sort through, the pagination works just fine.

Is there a way that I can run the pagination script on load so it forcibly only shows the first 9 items?

For the sake of posting, here is the pagination js I am using.

```
pageSize = 9;
showPage = function(page) {
$(".result-item").hide();
$(".result-item").each(function(n) {
    if (n >= pageSize * (page - 1) && n < pageSize * page)
        $(this).show();
});        
}

showPage(1);

$("#pagination li a").click(function() {
$("#pagination li a").removeClass("current");
$(this).addClass("current");
showPage(parseInt($(this).text())) 
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: is this wrapped inside document ready?  if not, then at least `showPage(1);` should be.

Comment: when you call showPage(1) data hasn't finished loading yet so there's nothing to paginate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move `showPage(1)` to `getJSON` callback -> [codepen](http://codepen.io/frontendguy/pen/adgVyz)

You should make list items not visible at first to reduce "blink"

Answer (score 0):

wrap `showPage(1);` in document ready.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    showPage(1);
});
```